# Cant save navigation settings - Missing permissions although I am owner of the site

Tags: permissions, navigation, managed-navigation, term-set, settings

I would like to activate the feature that automatically generates a building structure on the right side of the navigation area. More precisely, I would like to select the following menu item:

**"Managed Navigation: Navigation elements are displayed using a managed metadata expression set"**

So I select this radiobutton and select my desired expression set . However, when I click on OK and want to save, the following error message appears:
"Sorry, you do not have access. "When I click on Request Access, I get a request from myself, because I am the owner of this Sitecollection (or whatever web pages are called in SharePoint)
I have been playing around with permissions for so long, creating new websites and so much more... it just doesn't work, no matter what I try.

Comment: Are you in the owners group, or a site collection admin?  It's possible that you need to be a site collection admin to set managed navigation.

Comment: Hello,
I have **created** this SharePoint website. So I'm in the **"owner of..." group**. I also added myself as a separate user and assigned myself the **permission level "Full access"**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Modern experience site, I am afraid you are out of luck.  As per the [callout box on this support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-managed-navigation-for-a-site-in-sharepoint-49a067dc-77d2-455d-9e77-250ec7cc0a6d), **"Managed navigation is only available on sites that use the SharePoint classic experience"**.

If you did create this as a "classic" site, be sure to enable the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature on the site collection level.  See [Enable publishing features](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518).

Comment: Okay, it's catastrophic for my organization. Are there alternatives?
We use SharePoint as a wiki. So we create modern pages in the standard library and in a newly added column we specify that it is a wiki page. The views are filtered accordingly so that only wiki pages are displayed. In addition, we have a column with a managed expression set and we don't just want to filter by it, but give users an orientation at first sight, if you know what I mean. So it would have been very helpful if the navigation menu would have included the expressions or tags and you could click through.